# We should not migrate questions in German to other sites

Tags: discussion

*The question has since been deleted on SO.*

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73775579/wie-kann-man-komposita-programmatisch-trennen) - [originally asked on GermanSE](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/71675/wie-kann-man-komposita-programmatisch-trennen) - was recently migrated to stackoverflow but currently the question and all answers are in German and thusly make it unsuitable for any other site on the SE network.

As such, questions in German should be closed, not migrated, or asked to be translated by the OP, before migrated.

Comment: I agree in principle. Unfortunately, when closing the question, we need to give a reason for it. And in case of "this question belongs to Stack Overflow" being the most suitable option there, there is no way around migrating the question, if this reason is picked. I guess, we  just need another option "out of scope here" in the list of possible close-reasons.

Comment: @JonathanScholbach: You can always close for a custom close reason.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Thanks! I must have overlooked this option. Apologies for creating the issue, and thanks for making me aware, infinitezero!